# Why does closed Android activity appear to retain objects?

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

first time asking here.
I have a simple Android app I am developing using Xamarin.
In the main activity, I have a button that launches a second activity with 2 fragments in a tab view arrangement.
I close that activity, either using back button or calling finish().
Using the debugger, when I launch the second activity again, I notice that all the objects declared in the fragments are not null and still seem to be instantiated.
Why is this, shouldn't launching the activity again behave like I am launching for the first time? What am I missing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The garbage collector will not clean up your objects everytime you call on finish, it will cleanup the objects when the memory is full and when space is needed. So if you do not give your objects the value "null" in the OnDestroy() method, they might still exist when you restart your second activity. Placing your objects inside your activity on null will not garantuee that the garbage collector will collect them faster, but it will help the GC to see that the activity can be removed from memory.

There are some type of object declaration you need to be carefull with, because they can create a reference to your class that never gets set to null, wich will cause a memory leak in your application ( the activity cannot be removed from the heap, and keeps getting recreated ). [Here](http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) are some pointers on how to avoid memoryleaks!

There is an interesting talk on memory managment and object lifetime [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk). I'd suggest you check it out too! Hope this helps.